# pyparsing: getting results from parsed data

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse some `SQL` statements (`CREATE TABLE` exactly) using `pyparsing`. For both database name and table table I have created identifiers:

```
identifier = (Combine(Optional('"') + Word(alphanums) + 
                      ZeroOrMore('_' + Word(alphanums)) + 
                      Optional('"')) & ~keywords_set)

database_name = identifier.setResultsName('database_name')
table_name = identifier.setResultsName('table_name')
```

I am also using this parsing method:

```
def parse(self, sql):
    try:
        tokens = self.create_table_stmt.parseString(sql)
        print tokens.database_name, tokens.table_name
        values = tokens.database_name, tokens.table_name
        print values
        return values
    except ParseException as error:
        print error
```

For following input:

```
    CreateTableParser().parse('''
CREATE TABLE "django"."django_site1" (
)''')
```

i get:

```
['"django"'] ['"django_site1"']
((['"django"'], {}), (['"django_site1"'], {}))
```

Why these are different? How can I just get the output in the first way, as simple lists? I only get it when I print those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `print a, b` and `print (a,b)`:

```
>>> a, b = "ab"
>>> a
'a'
>>> b
'b'
>>> print a, b
a b
>>> print (a, b)
('a', 'b')
```

`print a, b` prints *two* objects `a` and `b`. `print (a, b)` prints a single object the tuple `a, b`:

```
>>> w = sys.stdout.write
>>> _ = w(str(a)), w(' '), w(str(b)), w('\n')
a b
>>> _ = w(str((a,b))), w('\n')
('a', 'b')
```

Or to put it another way:

```
>>> class A:
...    def __str__(self):
...        return '1'
...    def __repr__(self):
...        return 'A()'
... 
>>> print A(), A()
1 1
>>> print (A(), A())
(A(), A())
```

`__str__` method is called when you do `str(obj)`. If there is no `__str__` method then `__repr__` method is called `repr(obj)`.